# How to find difference between 2 versions of the same song (one longer than the other)?

Tags: audio, mp3, files

I have two versions of the same song. One is longer than the other (9 minutes Vs 13.55 minutes). Since our program only allows 10 min max time, we have to use the shorter version. but the audio quality of the longer version is better. What is the way I can trim the longer version where it differs from the shorter version?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to do this, using a Digital Audio Workstation.

Lay both versions into their own track, ensuring that the start of both versions is aligned.

Now you will have to go through the shorter version manually and compare it with the longer version. When you come across an area that is different, make a cut in the shorter version and then move the new region along the timeline to find the point where it matches the longer version. Repeat this process until the song ends.

You will then be able to see which parts of the short version match with the longer version and then make your own arrangement of cuts from the longer version.

Comment: aww c'mon Mark, this can be done with two cassette machines and a quick finger on the pause button!  :)  +1

Comment: yeah, yeah.... of course. you're right. what was I thinking?